# Replicating Matlab's bwconvhull in OpenCV

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, convex-hull

I am currently in the process of rewriting a Matlab program into OpenCV and I cannot find an equivalent to the `bwconvhull` function.

The Matlab code does the following:

```
H = bwconvhull(W>0.5);
```

Where `W` is a matrix with floating point values (which got calculated from several distance maps in the previous part of the algorithm).

I have successfully found a way to calculate `W` itself in OpenCV - resulting `cv::Mat` with type `32FC1`.

My first attempt used the straightforward translation:

```
cv::convexHull(w>0.5, h);
```

This crashes with the following exception:

```
OpenCV(3.4.1) \opencv\modules\imgproc\src\convhull.cpp:137: 
error: (-215) total >= 0 && (depth == 5 || depth == 4) 
in function cv::convexHull
```

I have checked out the source code and found out the problem is the `Mat` type - (`>` operator produces `8U` mat, while algorithm seems to support only `32F` and `32S`). So I tried conversion:

```
cv::Mat w2;
w = (w > 0.5);
w.convertTo(w2, CV_32F);
cv::convexHull(w2, h);
```

But now the problem moves to the `total >= 0` condition, where `total` is `w.checkVector(2)`. I am unable to understand how to achieve this condition to hold true.

I have also tried the following approach with the same result:

```
cv::Mat w2 = w * ( w > 0.5 );
cv::convexHull(w2, h);
```

My other tries involved `cv::threshold` and `cv::findContours` but those failed in a similar fashion.

I am really inexperienced in OpenCV and will be grateful for any pointer in the right direction.

Comment: If you read the [documentation to `cv::convexHull`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=convexhull#convexhull), you’ll learn that it takes a point set as input, not an image. There are lots of examples out there for using this function, including how to extract the boundary of the binary objects in the image.

Comment: The above comment is correct. You could find the contours of the object first, and then run `convexHull()` on the contour points. Alternatively you could just get the non-zero indices for the binary image and push that through.

Comment: CrisLuengo and AlexanderReynolds , thank you for pointing me to the right direction, I have followed the sample here and got it working - https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/hull/hull.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@CrisLuengo and @AlexanderReynolds have pointed me in the right direction, thank you both very much.

What I was missing was the `findContours` step to first retrieve the contours of the image and only then run it through the `convexHull` function. I have tried the `findContours` call before asking the question, but I must have chosen the arguments incorrectly. To get it working I have basically replicated the [sample code here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/hull/hull.html).